# Stationarize count based time series data

Tags: time-series, forecasting, data-transformation

I have a count based time series sequence with lot of 0s.

Usually to achieve stationarity we can do the following transform:

```
1. Differencing (Single, Double or seasonal)
2. Log
```

When I try differencing, I get negative values which is not applicable in this case. So I am trying to use

```
log(value +1 ). Since log(0) is inf
```

transformation. But I read some posts which is against log transformation of count based data.

Any suggestions to what are the transformations that I could consider in this case to achieve stationarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I try differencing, I get negative values which is not applicable in this case.

Negative values shouldn't be problem, even if the original series is all positive count values. 
To understand why, you need to think of the meaning of differencing: Differencing is the discrete equivalent of differentiation for continuous variables. It is perfectly possible to have a continuous function that is always positive but still has a negative slope (i.e. a negative derivative) in some places.

> Any suggestions to what are the transformations that I could consider in this case to achieve stationarity.

Box-Cox and power transforms are alternatives to differencing for making series stationary, although I don't know how suitable they are for count series.

If you are focusing on count series, you might want to check out the methods mentioned in this [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/351078/89649)